# I have written code for Get API in .NET Core and get an error running it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, webapi

```
public class GetPurchaseOrder
{
    public class GetPurchaseOrderListQuery : IQuery<IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderHeaderDto>>
    {
        public GetPurchaseOrderListQuery()
        {
        }

        internal class Validator : AbstractValidator<GetPurchaseOrderListQuery>
        {
            public Validator()
            {
            }
        }

        internal class Handler : IRequestHandler<GetPurchaseOrderListQuery, ResultModel<IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderHeaderDto>>>
        {
            private readonly IRepository<PurchaseOrderHeader> _purchaseOrderHeaderRepository;
            private readonly IRepository<Vendor> _vendorRepository;

            public Handler(IRepository<PurchaseOrderHeader> purchaseOrderHeaderRepository, IRepository<Vendor> vendorRepository)
            {
                _purchaseOrderHeaderRepository = purchaseOrderHeaderRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(purchaseOrderHeaderRepository));
                _vendorRepository = vendorRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vendorRepository));
            }

            public async Task<ResultModel<IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderHeaderDto>>> Handle(GetPurchaseOrderListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var data = await _purchaseOrderHeaderRepository.GetAllAsync();
                var vendorList = await _vendorRepository.GetAllAsync();

                var result = (from poList in data
                              join vList in vendorList on poList.VendorId equals vList.Id
                              select new
                              {
                                  poList.Id,
                                  poList.Date,
                                  poList.VendorId,
                                  vList.Name
                              }).ToList();

                return ResultModel<IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderHeaderDto>>.Create(result.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`4[System.Guid,System.DateTime,System.Guid,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PosService.DataContracts.Dtos.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderHeaderDto]'.

Could you tell me how to fix this error and what I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: If you're a beginner don't rush to use supposedly "best practices". Start with the documentation tutorials. That "repository" isn't a repository, it's a very *bad* practice. So are the explicit JOINs in LINQ. A DbContext is already a repository, one that automatically generates JOIN clauses from the *relations* between objects. You're working with objects and their relations, not tables and JOINs.

Comment: The error itself is pretty clear - it tells you that the result of the LINQ query isn't a `PurchaseOrderHeaderDto` because it simply isn't. It's a different type, created when you used `new {...}`. Use `new PurchaseOrderHeaderDto` if you want to map the results to that class.  `result` is already a `List<T>`, there's no need to call `ToList()` twice.

Comment: Assuming this is a practice project, I'd strongly suggest just deleting it and starting with a documentation tutorial, eg [Tutorial: Get started with EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0). You need to understand what you're working with before you decide whether it needs improving

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
var result = (from poList in data
                              join vList in vendorList on poList.VendorId equals vList.Id
                              select new PurchaseOrderHeaderDto
                              {
                                  Id= poList.Id,
                                  Date=poList.Date,
                                  VendorId=poList.VendorId,
                                  Name= vList.Name
                              }).ToList();

                return ResultModel<IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderHeaderDto>>.Create(result);
```